# Java 7 specification: variable identifiers are names, but field names are not? Why?

Tags: java, java-7, jls

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.2

Specification says:

> In determining the meaning of a name (§6.5), the context in which the name appears is
>   taken into account. The rules of §6.5 distinguish among contexts where a name must denote
>   (refer to) a package (§6.5.3), a type (§6.5.5), a variable or value in an expression
>   (§6.5.6), or a method (§6.5.7).

So, as far as I understand, names can only denote the above entities - which do not contain *fields*.

This seems to be in line with the statements made a bit below:

> Not all identifiers in a program are a part of a name. Identifiers are also used in the
>   following situations:
>
> - ...
> - In field access expressions (§15.11), where an identifier occurs after a "." token to
>     indicate a member of an object that is the value of an expression or the keyword super
>     that appears before the "." token
> - ...

So, my question is: what is the reason for this distinction between local variables and fields?

Comment: Have you read the example that follows and the explanation that comes with it?

Comment: Yes, and it only made me more confused. If you could pinpoint how it answers my question, that would be nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important part is:

> The rules of §6.5 distinguish among contexts where a name must denote
>   (refer to) a package (§6.5.3), a type (§6.5.5), **a variable or value in
>   an expression (§6.5.6)**, or a method (§6.5.7).

A reference to a field is *also* a **name** in this context because it is a value in an expression. (§6.5.6)

There are many points at which this is explained in §6.5.6, I've highlighted a few in bold below:

> 6.5.6.1. Simple Expression Names
>
> If an expression name consists of a single Identifier, then there must
>   be exactly one declaration denoting either a local variable,
>   parameter, or **field visible (§6.4.1)** at the point at which the
>   Identifier occurs. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
>
> If the declaration denotes an **instance variable (§8.3)**, the expression
>   name must appear within the declaration of an instance method (§8.4),
>   constructor (§8.8), instance initializer (§8.6), or instance variable
>   initializer (§8.3.2.2).

[...]

> 6.5.6.2. Qualified Expression Names
>
> If an expression name is of the form Q.Id, then Q has already been
>   classified as a package name, a type name, or **an expression name**.
>
> [...]
>
> If Q is an expression name, let T be the type of the expression Q:
>
> If T is not a reference type, a compile-time error occurs.
>
> If there is not exactly one accessible (§6.6) member of the type T
>   that is a **field named Id**, then a compile-time error occurs.

[etc. etc.]